# Figure out database problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

At the beginning I would like to say that I am not expert in this domain and It is problematic to describe all nuances. I work on Rails application which uses Mysql database. Our DB has grown and now we have seriously problems with performance. In our app we have two features (for example sync with mobile) which process much data and It causes our database hang. We use newrelic to monitoring which confirmed that we have problems with those two parts of app. My main question is how to profile my app to figure out which actions make the biggest problem? Which tools I can use? Do you have any tips what I can do/configure DB to improve performance? What action I should do to find out where the problem is (next small step)? I know that those question are very general but I am junior in this domain and new in rails. I believe that more question will appear after your answers ;)

Comment: You can begin with logging SQL calls. Rails reflects the time taken to complete a call. Improve upon calls which take a lot of time. Once you have the culprit calls located. This question would lead to more questions. Questions that are biased towards SQL.

Comment: Yes I know that I asked about to much things. But maybe someone will describe me here some step which I can do. The biggest question for me is how i can improve my mysql config. How to find out problems with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what is the size of db, like how many tables and avg no of rows per table. With the basic details available in your question, here are few steps you can look upon.

Regarding data sync with mobile. First step should be avoid heavy processing on the fly rather use background jobs to process the data and store in tables what actually needs to be sent to mobile . So in that case you will avoid multiple queries, rather 1-2 queries should fetch the entire data with minimum processsing.

I'm sure you must have applied indexing and active model relationship has been properly managed. It would actually help if you can post some models and basic relationship between them . Also explan in brief how the sync is being done and apis being handled.

Use benchmarking to figure the time to fetch data and keep a watch on the logs when processing data. There are some better benchmarking tooks available.